# DepthFirstSearch java implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, undirected-graph

I am trying to learn how to implement graphs (Depth First Search) into java.
And here is a piece of code that I do not understand what a character means in here. It is about this piece of code:

```
    private void dfs(Graph G, int v) {
    count++;
    marked[v] = true;
    for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
        if (!marked[w]) {
            dfs(G, w);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand what "w" is about?!

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the full code, maybe it will help you more to know excatly what is going on here:

```
package edu.princeton.cs.algs4;

public class DepthFirstSearch {
    private boolean[] marked;    // marked[v] = is there an s-v path?
    private int count;           // number of vertices connected to s


    public DepthFirstSearch(Graph G, int s) {
        marked = new boolean[G.V()];
        validateVertex(s);
        dfs(G, s);
    }


    private void dfs(Graph G, int v) {
        count++;
        marked[v] = true;
        for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
            if (!marked[w]) {
                dfs(G, w);
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean marked(int v) {
        validateVertex(v);
        return marked[v];
    }


    public int count() {
        return count;
    }


    private void validateVertex(int v) {
        int V = marked.length;
        if (v < 0 || v >= V)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("vertex " + v + " is not between 0 and " + (V-1));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        Graph G = new Graph(in);
        int s = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        DepthFirstSearch search = new DepthFirstSearch(G, s);
        for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
            if (search.marked(v))
                StdOut.print(v + " ");
        }

        StdOut.println();
        if (search.count() != G.V()) StdOut.println("NOT connected");
        else                         StdOut.println("connected");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: `w` is about adding an edge to the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you just posted part of your code, I beleive that `w` stands for each node that is adjacent to the current node `v`.  Or we can say that `w` stands for each element in `G.adj(v)`,which should be an arrayList or something like that.

See `foreach` loop grammar here:[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Updates:

Read the detailed code, though lack of the defination of `Graph`, still sure that 
what has been answered should be reasonable.

Comment: I just edited the code, I posted the full code maybe this will help you to clarify what that excatly is. Thanks for the link you sent, I'll look into it for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop in your example is a `foreach` loop. `G.adj(v)` most likely returns some collection. `W` represents each single element in the collection. For every element `W` in that collection do something.